# Magento 2 : Codazon Fastest Theme js not loading propperly

Tags: magento2, theme, knockoutjs, requirejs

I Have Installed Codazon Fastest Theme on my Manto2 site.i am facing an issue with js loading.

here is my system configuration below.
magento version : 2.4.5
PHP: 8.0
theme: Codazon Fastest Theme

after installing the theme third-party extension js stopped working. I tried to include js
using require js but the result was the same. here I have mentioned js files that cause errors.

```
 var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': {
                'Codazon_AjaxCartPro/js/catalog-add-to-cart': true
            }
        }

    },
    map: {
        '*': {
            'codazonSidebar': 'Codazon_AjaxCartPro/js/sidebar',
            'catalogAddToCart': 'Codazon_AjaxCartPro/js/catalog-add-to-cart',
            'Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart': 'Codazon_AjaxCartPro/js/catalog-add-to-cart',
            'mage/dataPost': 'Codazon_AjaxCartPro/js/ajax-post',
            'defaultMageDataPost': 'mage/dataPost' 
        }
    },
    deps: [
        'Codazon_AjaxCartPro/js/ajax-post'
    ]
};
```

> path : /app/code/Codazon/AjaxCartPro/view/frontend/web/js/ajax-post.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/template',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'defaultMageDataPost'
   ], function($, mageTemplate, uiConfirm, customerData) {

    if (typeof window.cdzBuilAjaxPost == 'undefined') {
        window.cdzBuilAjaxPost = true;
        var dataPost = $(document).data('mageDataPost');
        if (typeof dataPost != 'undefined') {
            
            var isCompareIndexPage = function() {
                return $('body').hasClass('catalog-product_compare-index');
            }
            
            var $loginPopup = $('<div class="ajax-lgfm-popup md-dialog-container account-popup" id="ajax-lgfm-popup" data-cdzpopup>').appendTo('body');
            $('body').trigger('cdzBuildPopup');
            $loginPopup.parents('.popup-ajax-lgfm-popup').first().addClass('popup-account-popup');
            dataPost.ajaxActions = {};
            dataPost.$msgContainer = $('<div class="cdz-msg-container fixed">').appendTo('body');
            dataPost.isAjaxAction = function(action) {
                if (typeof this.ajaxActions[action] == 'undefined') {
                    var self = this;
                    self.ajaxActions[action] = false;
                    $.each(cdzAjaxPost.replacedActions, function(needSearch, replacement) {
                        if (action.search(needSearch) > -1) {
                            self.ajaxActions[action] = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
                return this.ajaxActions[action];
            };
            dataPost.oldPostData = dataPost.postData;
            dataPost.filterAction = function(action) {
                $.each(cdzAjaxPost.replacedActions, function(needSearch, replacement) {
                    if (action.search(needSearch) > -1) {
                        action = replacement;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                return action;
            };
            dataPost.updateMessages = function(messages) {
                var self = this;
                if (messages) {
                    self.displayMessages(messages);
                } else {
                    $.get(cdzAjaxPost.updateMsgUrl, {_: $.now()}, function(rs) {
                        if (rs.messages) {
                            if (rs.messages.messages) {
                                self.displayMessages(rs.messages.messages);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            dataPost.displayMessages = function(messages) {
                var self = this;
                self.$msgContainer.show();
                $.each(messages, function(i, msg) {
                    var $message = $('<div class="message cdz-translator">').addClass(msg.type).html('<span>' + msg.text + '</span>').prependTo(self.$msgContainer);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $message.fadeOut(2000, 'swing', function() {
                            $message.remove();
                            if (!self.$msgContainer.children().length) {
                                self.$msgContainer.hide();
                            }
                        });
                    }, 3000);
                });
            };
            dataPost.ajaxPost = function(params) {
                var self = this;
                var formKey = $(this.options.formKeyInputSelector).val();
                if (formKey) {
                    params.data['form_key'] = formKey;
                }
                var action = self.filterAction(params.action);
                var postParam = params;
                if (self.notLogin && (action.search('wishlist') > -1)) {
                    self._displayLoginForm(false, postParam);
                } else {
                    postParam.data.currentUrl = document.URL;
                    if (isCompareIndexPage()) {
                        postParam.data.isCompareIndexPage = true;
                    }
                    $('body').addClass('cdz-ajaxpost-proccessing');
                    $.ajax({
                        url: action,
                        data: postParam.data,
                        type: 'POST',
                        showLoader: true,
                        success: function(rs) {
                            if (rs.message) {
                                self.displayMessages([{
                                    type: (rs.success?'success':'error'),
                                    text: rs.message
                                }]);
                            } else {
                                self.updateMessages();
                            }
                            if (rs.login_form_html) {
                                self.notLogin = true;
                                self._displayLoginForm(rs.login_form_html, postParam, rs.after_login_url);
                            }
                            
                            if (action.search('wishlist/remove') > -1) {
                                $('body').trigger('cdzWishlistItemRemoved', [params, rs]);
                            }
                            if ((action.search('wishlist/fromcart') > -1) || (action.search('wishlist/moveallfromcart') > -1)) {
                                $('body').trigger('cdzWishlistItemMovedFromCart', [params, rs]);
                            }
                            if (action.search('compare/remove') > -1) {
                                $('body').trigger('cdzCompareItemRemoved', [params, rs]);
                            }
                            $('body').trigger('materialUpdated');
                            $('body').trigger('contentUpdated');
                            if (action.search('wishlist') > -1) {
                                customerData.reload(['wishlist'], false);
                            }
                            if (action.search('compare') > -1) {
                                customerData.reload(['compare-products'], false);
                            }
                        }
                    }).always(function() {
                        $('body').removeClass('cdz-ajaxpost-proccessing');
                    });
                }
            };
            dataPost.postData = function(params) {
                var self = this;
                if (this.isAjaxAction(params.action)) {
                    if (params.data.confirmation) {
                        uiConfirm({
                            content: params.data.confirmationMessage,
                            actions: {
                                confirm: function () {
                                    self.ajaxPost(params);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        self.ajaxPost(params);
                    }
                } else {
                    this.oldPostData(params);
                }
            };
            
            dataPost._displayLoginForm = function(html, params, action) {
                referer = btoa(referer);
                if (html) {
                    $loginPopup.data('action', action);
                    var referer = action + 'product/' + params.data.product + '/referer/' + btoa(document.URL) + '/form_key/' + params.data.form_key;
                    $loginPopup.html(html); var $form = $loginPopup.find('form');
                    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="referer">').val(btoa(referer)));
                } else {
                    action = $loginPopup.data('action');
                    var referer = action + 'product/' + params.data.product + '/referer/' + btoa(document.URL) + '/form_key/' + params.data.form_key;
                    $loginPopup.find('form [name="referer"]').val(btoa(referer));
                }
                $loginPopup.trigger('triggerPopup');
            }
            
            $.widget('codazon.customDataPost', $.mage.dataPost, {
                postData: function(params) {
                    dataPost.postData(params);
                }
            });
            $.mage.dataPost = $.codazon.customDataPost;           
            
            $('body').on('cdzWishlistItemRemoved', function(e, params, rs) {
                var id = params.data.item;
                var $wishlistForm = $('#wishlist-view-form');
                if ($wishlistForm.length) {
                    $wishlistForm.find('.product-item[id="item_' + id +'"]').fadeOut(500, 'swing', function() {
                        $(this).remove();
                        if ($wishlistForm.find('.product-item').length == 0) {
                            var $msg = $('<div class="message info empty">').html('<span>' + cdzAjaxPost.wishlistEmptyMsg + '</span>').prependTo($wishlistForm);
                            $wishlistForm.find('.actions-toolbar, .products-grid.wishlist').remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            $('body').on('cdzWishlistItemMovedFromCart', function(e, params, rs) {
                if (rs.success) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.location.reload();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
            
            $('body').on('cdzCompareItemRemoved', function(e, params, rs) {
                if (rs.compare_list_html && isCompareIndexPage()) {
                    var $oldCompareList = $('.table-wrapper.comparison').first();
                    if ($oldCompareList.length) {
                        $('.action.print.hidden-print').remove();
                        var $newCompareList = $('<div>').html(rs.compare_list_html);
                        $oldCompareList.hide().before($newCompareList);
                        $oldCompareList.remove();
                        $newCompareList.children().first().unwrap();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

> path : /app/code/Codazon/AjaxCartPro/view/frontend/web/js/ajaxcart.js

```
    define([
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'codazonSidebar',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, paypalCheckout) {
    'use strict';
    var sidebarCart = $('[data-block="footer_minicart"]');
    var addToCartCalls = 0;
    var sidebarInitialized = false;

    function initSidebar() {
        if (sidebarCart.data('mageSidebar')) {
            sidebarCart.codazonSidebar('update');
        }
        sidebarCart.trigger('contentUpdated');
        if (sidebarInitialized) {
            return false;
        }
        sidebarInitialized = true;
        sidebarCart.codazonSidebar({
            "targetElement": "#footer-mini-cart",
            "url": {
                "checkout": window.checkout.checkoutUrl,
                "update": window.checkout.updateItemQtyUrl,
                "remove": window.checkout.removeItemUrl,
                "loginUrl": window.checkout.customerLoginUrl,
                "isRedirectRequired": window.checkout.isRedirectRequired
            },
            "button": {
                "checkout": "#footer-cart-btn-checkout",
                "remove": ".item a.action.delete",
                "close": ""
            },
            "minicart": {
                "list": "",
                "content": "",
                "qty": "",
                "subtotal": ""
            },
            "item": {
                "qty": "input.cart-item-qty",
                "button": "button.update-cart-item"
            },
            "confirmMessage": $.mage.__(
                'Are you sure you would like to remove this item from the shopping cart?'
            )
        });
        //fix paypal express checkout cart button not work on footer cart
        $( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
            if( settings.url.indexOf('customer/section/load/?sections') >= 0){
                $('.footer-cart-actions [data-action="checkout-form-submit"]').off('click');
                $('.footer-cart-actions [data-action="checkout-form-submit"]').click(function(){
                    $('[data-action="checkout-form-submit"]:first').click();
                });
            }
        });
        //=== end fix ===
    }

    return Component.extend({
        ajaxcart: ko.observable({}),
        crosssell: ko.observable({}),
        addedItem: ko.observable({}),
        cartSidebar: ko.observable({summary_count: false}),
        toggleFooterSidebar: function(){
            $('#footer-cart-trigger').toggleClass('active');
            $('#footer-mini-cart').slideToggle(300);    
        },
        initSidebar: initSidebar,
        initialize: function () {
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            this.addedItem({success:false});
            this.cartSidebar = customerData.get('cart');
            window.addedItem = self.addedItem;
            window.ajaxcart = self.ajaxcart;
            window.crosssell = self.crosssell;
            window.cartSidebar = self.cartSidebar;
            $('#cart-footer').show();
            initSidebar();
            this.cartSidebar.subscribe(function () {
                addToCartCalls--;
                sidebarInitialized = false;             
                initSidebar();
            }, this);
            $('[data-block="minicart"]').on('contentLoading', function(event) {
                addToCartCalls++;               
            });
            var $ajaxPopup = $('#ajax-cart-container');
            /*$ajaxPopup.modal({
            innerScroll: true,
            trigger: '.tocart',
            wrapperClass: 'ajaxcart-modal',
            buttons: [],
            opened: function(){
            window.addedItem({success:false});
            },
            closed: function(){
            }   
            });*/
        },

    });
});
```

> path : /app/code/Codazon/AjaxCartPro/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js

```
    define([
    "jquery",
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert',
    'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm',
    "mage/decorate"
     ], function($, authenticationPopup, customerData, alert, confirm){

    $.widget('mage.codazonSidebar', {
        options: {
            isRecursive: true,
            maxItemsVisible: 3
        },
        scrollHeight: 0,

        /**
         * Create sidebar.
         * @private
         */
        _create: function () {
            this._initContent();

        },

        /**
         * Update sidebar block.
         */
        update: function () {
            $(this.options.targetElement).trigger('contentUpdated');
            this._calcHeight();
            this._isOverflowed();
        },

        _initContent: function() {
            var self = this,
                events = {};

            this.element.decorate('list', this.options.isRecursive);
            /*events['click ' + this.options.button.close] = function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $(self.options.targetElement).dropdownDialog("close");
            };*/

            events['click ' + this.options.button.checkout] = $.proxy(function() {
                var cart = customerData.get('cart'),
                    customer = customerData.get('customer');

                if (!customer().firstname && !cart().isGuestCheckoutAllowed) {
                    if (this.options.url.isRedirectRequired) {
                        location.href = this.options.url.loginUrl;
                    } else {
                        authenticationPopup.showModal();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
                location.href = this.options.url.checkout;
            }, this);

            events['click ' + this.options.button.remove] =  function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                confirm({
                    content: self.options.confirmMessage,
                    actions: {
                        confirm: function () {
                            self._removeItem($(event.currentTarget));
                        },
                        always: function (event) {
                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
                        }
                    }
                });
            };
            events['keyup ' + this.options.item.qty] = function(event) {
                self._showItemButton($(event.target));
            };
            events['click ' + this.options.item.button] = function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                self._updateItemQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };
            events['focusout ' + this.options.item.qty] = function(event) {
                self._validateQty($(event.currentTarget));
            };
            events['click .edit-icon'] = function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                self._showOptions($(event.currentTarget));
            }
            this._on(this.element, events);
            //this._calcHeight();
            //this._isOverflowed();
        },

        /**
         * Add 'overflowed' class to minicart items wrapper element
         *
         * @private
         */
        _isOverflowed: function() {
            var list = $(this.options.minicart.list),
                cssOverflowClass = 'overflowed';

            if (this.scrollHeight > list.innerHeight()) {
                list.parent().addClass(cssOverflowClass);
            } else {
                list.parent().removeClass(cssOverflowClass);
            }
        },

        _showItemButton: function(elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
            var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');
            if (this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                $('#cdz-update-cart-item-' + itemId).show('fade', 300);
            } else if (elem.val() == 0) {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            } else {
                this._hideItemButton(elem);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @param origin - origin qty. 'data-item-qty' attribute.
         * @param changed - new qty.
         * @returns {boolean}
         * @private
         */
        _isValidQty: function(origin, changed) {
            return (origin != changed)
                && (changed.length > 0)
                && (changed - 0 == changed)
                && (changed - 0 > 0);
        },

        /**
         * @param {Object} elem
         * @private
         */
        _validateQty: function(elem) {
            var itemQty = elem.data('item-qty');

            if (!this._isValidQty(itemQty, elem.val())) {
                elem.val(itemQty);
            }
        },

        _hideItemButton: function(elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
            $('#cdz-update-cart-item-' + itemId).hide('fade', 300);
        },

        _updateItemQty: function(elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
            this._ajax(this.options.url.update, {
                item_id: itemId,
                item_qty: $('#cdz-cart-item-' + itemId + '-qty').val()
            }, elem, this._updateItemQtyAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after update qty
         *
         * @param elem
         */
        _updateItemQtyAfter: function(elem) {
            this._hideItemButton(elem);
        },

        _removeItem: function(elem) {
            var itemId = elem.data('cart-item');
            this._ajax(this.options.url.remove, {
                item_id: itemId
            }, elem, this._removeItemAfter);
        },

        /**
         * Update content after item remove
         *
         * @param elem
         * @param response
         * @private
         */
        _removeItemAfter: function(elem, response) {
        },
        /**
         * @param url - ajax url
         * @param data - post data for ajax call
         * @param elem - element that initiated the event
         * @param callback - callback method to execute after AJAX success
         */
        _ajax: function(url, data, elem, callback) {
            $.extend(data, {
                'form_key': $.mage.cookies.get('form_key')
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: data,
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    elem.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                },
                complete: function() {
                    elem.attr('disabled', null);
                }
            })
                .done(function(response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        callback.call(this, elem, response);
                    } else {
                        var msg = response.error_message;
                        if (msg) {
                            alert({
                                content: $.mage.__(msg)
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
                .fail(function(error) {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
        },

        _showOptions: function (elem) {
            var $elemTarget = elem.parent().parent();
            var $optionTarget = $elemTarget.find('.hover-sec');
            var $listItem = $elemTarget.parent();

            if ( $optionTarget.hasClass('show-options') ) {
                $optionTarget.removeClass('show-options');
            } else {
                $listItem.find('div.hover-sec.show-options').removeClass('show-options');
                $optionTarget.addClass('show-options');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Calculate height of minicart list
         *
         * @private
         */
        _calcHeight: function() {
            var self = this,
                height = 0,
                counter = this.options.maxItemsVisible,
                target = $(this.options.minicart.list);

            target.children().each(function () {
                var outerHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

                if (counter-- > 0) {
                    height += outerHeight;
                }
                self.scrollHeight += outerHeight;
            });

            target.height(height);
        }
    });

    return $.mage.codazonSidebar;
});
```